Help with understanding the definition of subgroup distortion
I would like some help understanding this result about subgroup distortion that appeared in Wikipedia page.

In a tower of groups $K \leq H \leq G$, the distortion of $K$ in $G$ is at least the distortion of $H$ in $G$.

If we let $K$ be the trivial subgroup, and suppose $H$ has exponential distortion in $G$. In this case, the distortion of $K$ in $G$ is less than the distortion of $H$ in $G$. Did I misunderstand something here, or are there additional conditions we need to put on $K$ and $H$?
Thank you for reading.

This would be neither the first nor the last time someone wrote something wrong on Wikipedia.

My most generous guess is that this represents a brain fart on the part of the wikipedia user who wrote that post. It can be corrected to say "the distortion of $K$ in $G$ is at least the distortion of $K$ in $H$".

Fixed the wikipedia page.

Wikipedia is wrong (and by “wrong” I mean totally misguided — not only is this false, it reflects a complete lack of understanding of this concept).  Saying that $H$ is exponentially distorted in $G$ means that there are elements $h \in H$ whose word length in $H$ is much longer than their word length in $G$.  But these bad elements might be very special, and if $K < H$ then there is no reason to expect that $K$ contains those bad elements.  Your example of the trivial subgroup is a fine example of this.
